# Handling Dollar Sign in Input numeric text

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm running into an issue with my Python program.

In fact, I have a sales price input which can contain a dollar sign and must respect the following constraints :

1. It must be numeric
2. The sales price must be at least $100, including dollars and cents

The problem I'm facing is : if the user inputs a sales price including a dollar sign, how to "ignore" it in order to determine if the input is numeric ? The same issue applies when it comes to a decimal point.

Also, note that :

- If the input is not a numeric entry, I would like it to prompt *"price must be numeric"*.
- If the entry is less than $100, I would like it to prompt *"Price must be at least $100"*.

This is what I have so far :

```
salesPrice= input("What is the sales price of the new phone? ")

if salesPrice[0]=="$":
    val= int(salesPrice[1:])
    if val < 100
        print('Price must be at least $100')
    else:
        price=float(salesPrice[1:])
elif ValueError:
    print('Price must be numeric')
else:
    if salesPrice[0]!= '$':
        if salesPrice[0:]< Min_price:
        print('Price must be at least $100')
        else:
            price=float(salesPrice[0:])
```

Comment: Do you use Python 2.7 or 3.x? Please make up your mind. The answer to your question depends on your choice.

Comment: sorry about that i am using 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```
salesPrice= input("What is the sales price of the new phone? ")

if salesPrice.startswith("$"):

    amount = salesPrice.replace("$", "").strip()
    if amount.isnumeric():
        val = int(amount)
        if val < 100:
            print('Price must be at least $100')
        else:
            price=float(val)
    else:
        print('Price must be numeric')
else:
    if salesPrice.isnumeric():
        salesPrice = int(salesPrice)
        if salesPrice < 100:
            print('Price must be at least $100')
        else:
            price=float(salesPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Python3 since your use of `input()` doesn't throw a `SyntaxError` upon receiving a non-numeric string. Either way, only the input should change. For Python3:

```py
salesPrice = input("What is the sales price of the new phone? ").replace('$', '')
try:
    salesPrice = float(salesPrice)
    if salesPrice < 100.:
        print("Price must be at least $100")
except ValueError:
    print("Price must be numeric")
```

And for Python 2:

```py
salesPrice = raw_input("What is the sales price of the new phone? ").replace('$', '')
try:
    salesPrice = float(salesPrice)
    if salesPrice < 100.:
        print("Price must be at least $100")
except ValueError:
    print("Price must be numeric")
```

For both, you can check if a string is a float with a simple [try/except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float).

Comment: Thank you so much, the .replace is something i haven't learned yet so that is very helpful!

Comment: no prob! Feel free to mark this as the answer if you don't have further questions

Answer (score 0):

I would separate two concerns: dealing $ sign and number logic, separately.

```py
salesPrice= input("What is the sales price of the new phone? ")

# remove the optional $ sign
if salesPrice[0]=="$":
    salesPrice = salesPrice[1:]

# your number logic
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following if you would like to handle **any currency** and not just dollars.

The regular expression code extracts the numbers and checks if it is less than 100 or not.

```py
import re

input_price = input("What is the sales price of the new phone? ")
lst_find = re.findall('(\d+)', input_price)
if len(lst_find) != 0:
    price = int(lst_find[0])
    if price < 100:
        print('Price must be atleast $100')
else:
    print('Price must be numeric')
```